# Problem with the proof that galois extension of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_n)^\times$

Tags: galois-theory, roots-of-unity

I'm trying to understand a proof that galois extension of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_n)^\times$.

I can see why there is an injection of $\text{Gal}(x^n-1)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_n)^\times$. However, when it comes to proving the surjectivity, I am confused.

Given $\zeta$ a primitive $n$th root of unity and $r \in (\mathbb{Z}_n)^\times$. Why is it sufficient to show that $\zeta$ and $\zeta^r$ have the same minimal polynomial ? Isn't it possible that for $\zeta$ and $\zeta^r$ to have the same minimal polynomial without having an automorphisme $\tau$ such that $\tau(\zeta) = \zeta^r$ ?

Comment: that "the splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $\Bbb Q$ has Galois group isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$" or "the Galois group of $x^n-1$ over $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times,$ or slightly more loosely, "the Galois group of $x^n-1$ is $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$" (indeed, the isomorphism is in fact *canonical*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it possible that for $\zeta$ and $\zeta^r$ to have the same minimal polynomial without having an automorphisme $\tau$ such that $\tau(\zeta) = \zeta^r$ ?

No.  If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same minimal polynomial $p(X)$ over $K$, then $K[\alpha]\cong K[\beta] \cong K[X]/(p(X))$.

It is a basic result of Galois theory that this isomorphism extends to an automorphism of the algebraic closure, though that is not even necessary in this case.

Comment: You don't need to extend it to the algebraic closure in this particular instance, because $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is the splitting field of $x^n-1$. Thus the composite map $\Bbb Q(\zeta)\cong\Bbb Q[T]/\Phi_n(T)\cong\Bbb Q(\zeta^r)$ is a field isomorphism, and since $\Bbb Q(\zeta)=\Bbb Q(\zeta^r)$, it is an automorphism. However to prove more generally that the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial acts transitively on its roots, one must resort to extending isomorphisms to (Galois) closures.

Comment: @anon Good point.